# Django2.2: best way to confirm form without js

Tags: python, django

I want to implement this algorithm:

1. user submits a modelform
2. if clean() method raises an error, I don't want to show form again. I want user to see a confirmation page with "confirm" and "cancel" buttons.

For example,

> The Book with the same name already exists.
>
> Do you want to save one more book with this name?
>
> Yes / Cancel

What is the best way in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clean() method is called when you call is_valid() in your view.  So in your view, you should have something like:

```
if not my_form.is_valid():
    return render(request, 'confirmation_page_template.html', {})
```

Comment: thanks. what (and how) shoud I pass to the  "confirmation_page_template.html" to save the form in this template page?

Comment: The template does not handle that.  The template only displays what the user should see.  You should handle saving the data from the form in your view.  So in the view, take the data passed from the form in the my_form.cleaned_data array, and then save it to the database or do whatever else you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/) you should override the method `form_invalid` according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin):

> **form_invalid(form)**
>
> Renders a response, providing the invalid form as context.

Usually, this method returns to the same view showing the form errors, you could use any other view, and having the failing form gives you the chance to [message](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/) the user with the errors if you like.

### However ...

You should think about giving the option of confirming a non-valid form, you shouldn't give the user the option of confirming bad data.

Comment: I've updated my question with an example. I don't use any CBW. I don't want just to show errors, I want to warn user about some condition and leave an ability to save the form.